# Google spreadsheet get exchange rate using date column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I cannot make it work and I have tried every solution that I have found.

I have a column with dates and I need to get the exchange rate of USD-EUR at this specific data (close or open value work fine).

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you try to use `;` instead of `,` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `;` instead of `,`.

It may have to do with the spreadsheet location:

You can change that by going to:
`File => Spreadsheet Settings => then Change site location`

[image]

The date is the one giving you the error:

[image]

You need to format the date according to the country:

`11.25.1992 => 25.11.1992`

Comment: I changed both but still no luck. I have also formated my date. No clue what's the problem. here is the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T_FsBhH3W68eM49-YPH23FOIXUllWjP90b-oW0BruLU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you please give access to the file please ? create a dummy one if needed pls

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T_FsBhH3W68eM49-YPH23FOIXUllWjP90b-oW0BruLU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: yeah, was going to tell you it was the date, updated my answer with it